# Wrap binaries as nuget package

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, nuget-package

Is there a way to bundle OpenSSL or LibreSSL binaries as a nuget package? All I want is that I can have the complete folder zipped and published to nuget. Then reference it in my solution to have it downloaded somewhere relative to my project.

Answer (score 1):

1- Download [NuGetPackageExplorer](https://github.com/NuGetPackageExplorer/NuGetPackageExplorer)
2- In Nuget Package Explorer Select File>New and then select create a new package.
3- On the content tab add a folder names 'lib' and then add your dll files.
4- Save the package

for more info check Nuget Package Explorer manual in the same link.